# android UI inconsistent between phones

Tags: android

In the app I am working on, there is inconsistency between what is displayed in the Android Studio UI builder and the 2 phones I tested it on (A nexus 6p and an Xperia XZ Premium. They both have the same aspect ratio, with the 6p being 2560x1440 and XZ being 3840x2160 but scaled down to 1920x1080 during normal use if I understand correctly)

For instance: I have 3 buttons with a static width in dp at the top of the screen in a constraintlayout, and in the UI builder they go from one end of the screen to the other, each constrained to the left and evenly spaced. In the builder and on the 6p, it displays properly. However, on the XZ, it is but off.

After further testing, it seems the XZ always cuts off around 25dp on the right and bottom when the layout contains objects with set widths and lengths that cross into those missing 25dp. How do I fix this? The 6p displays everything just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using auto layout constraints to help adjust the dimensions. Something you should consider for the future is that you need move fragments, that will insure consistent UI over many versions of android phones and tablets currently in the market.

Android layout view can help you do all that.

[image]

Right click not the textfield/button that you want to set to a specific constraint and let the magic happen.